# Python spur: how to read output of long-running command

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to use the [spur](https://pypi.org/project/spur/) library to launch a long-running command via ssh then read and process the output from it one line at a time.  The documentation says you can pass a file object using `stdout=f` and run/spawn will call `stdout.write` for anything the subprocess writes to its stdout stream.  I hit on the idea of creating an `os.pipe()` to make this work, but it doesn't.  Can someone please suggest a fix.

NOTE: I've already got this working with `paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command` but the interface is a bit low-level for my needs, so I want to learn how to do it with `spur`.  Thanks!

```
import spur
import os

HOST = "rocky.lan"
USER = "rocky"
CMD  = "while sleep 1; do date; done"

r, w = os.pipe()

r = os.fdopen(r, 'rb')
w = os.fdopen(w, 'wb')

ssh = spur.SshShell(hostname=HOST, username=USER)
child = ssh.spawn(CMD, stdout=w)

for line in iter(r.readline, ""):
    print(line, end="")
```

Since someone is bound to ask, the parakimo code looks like this:-

```
from paramiko import SSHClient

HOST = "rocky.lan"
USER = "rocky"
CMD  = "while sleep 1; do date; done"

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect(HOST, username=USER)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(CMD)

for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered [parallel-ssh](https://parallel-ssh.org) which seems to have parted company from paramiko and gone for python-ssh/python-ssh2 instead.  A 5-minute test suggests that it combines paramiko's power with spur's simplicity, but sadly still doesn't support `~/.ssh/config`, so Perl's `Net::OpenSSH` is still my favourite :-)  Here's the code I got working with pssh:-

```
from pssh.clients import SSHClient

HOST = "rocky.lan"
USER = "rocky"
CMD  = "while sleep 1; do date; done"

ssh = SSHClient(host=HOST, user=USER)
cmd = ssh.run_command(CMD)

for line in cmd.stdout:
    print(line)
```

So this is an alternative, but really I still need to know how to read the subprocess's stdout using `spur`.